# How to set environment variables before each run of SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, spring-boot-test

I have a cucumber component test suite where each component test needs a new version of our spring boot app started with a specified set of environment variables. This is because the app reads the environment variables on startup and these determine how the app runs. Additionally, I am trying to run the tests in parallel, meaning that multiple copies of my spring boot app will need to be running at the same time with different environment variables passed to them

I've searched around the web quite alot and have successfully used @SpringBootTest and @DirtiesContext to restart the Spring boot app for each test, but I have not been able to figure out how to set the environment variables for the **first test**. @SpringBootTest starts before the method annotated with @Before is called -- where I set the environment variables for a test, so the first test never gets the proper environment variables set. Subsequent tests however do get the proper environment.

I could create a dummy test at the top of each feature file, but then running an individual test won't work and its hackish anyway

```
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes= TestExperimentApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext
@TestExecutionListeners(
        listeners = DirtyContextBeforeAndAfterClassTestExecutionListener.class, 
        mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)

public class StepDefs {
    @Before
    public void before() {
        // set environment variables for test
    }

    ... step methods ...
}
```

To reiterate, setting the environment variables once or in a static block won't work here. I need to set unique environment variables **for each component test**.

Does anyone know how I might be able to override/modify the behavior of @SpringBootTest to not start up the first time until @Before is run, or know of a better way to accomplish this?

Other approaches I have come up with are...

1. Manually starting application contexts for each test and keeping track of them (least favorite idea)
2. use Testcontainers (https://www.testcontainers.org/) to run the app locally with its Dockerfile

Comment: Does your app do one thing once? If so you may want to turn it into a spring command line app. That should also solve the testing problem.